# Regex - Remove single whitespace

Tags: php, regex

I´ve got a string that looks like this:

```
"T E S T  R E N T A L  A K T I E B O L A G"
```

And I want it to look like this:

```
"TEST RENTAL AKTIEBOLAG"
```

But I can´t seem to find the right regex expression for my problem. I would like to remove one single whitespace between each character.

Kind Regards / H

Comment: "T E S T  R E N T A L  A K T I E B O L A G".replace(/\s{1}(\S)/g, "$1")

Comment: `# (?! )#`: http://regex101.com/r/dU9yH2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the regex:

```
\s(\s)?
```

And replace with `$1`.

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/yH4rG0)

Answer (score 2):

An alternative solution to @Jerry's answer:

```
preg_replace('# (?! )#','',$text)
```

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/dU9yH2)

[3v4l.org demo](http://3v4l.org/9BYkj)

Answer (score 0):

you couldnt use `str_replace(' ', '', $your_string);` because it will return 
`"TESTRENTALAKTIEBOLAG"` and not `"TEST RENTAL AKTIEBOLAG"`

But you can use bellow code:

```
$my_string = "T E S T  R E N T A L  A K T I E B O L A G";
$string_a = str_replace('  ','+',$my_string);
$string_b = str_replace(' ','',$string_a );
$final_string = str_replace('+',' ',$string_b);

echo $final_string;
```

[3v4l.org](http://3v4l.org/5BvaN)

Answer (score -1):

```
str_replace(' ', '', $your_string);
```

Comment: That one just replaces all of my whitespaces, and that´s not what I want. Between each character there are one whitespace and between each word there are two whitespaces. I would like to remove all whitespaces except one between each word.