# How to remove single white space but not multiple?

Tags: c++

I know there are some questions concerning this topic, but I would like to know how one should approach this problem without the use of regex?

Regex solutions are also welcome because the best solution I currently know is / (?! ), but this one still removes one white space from all of them.

For example, I would like to remove all singular white spaces from a string:

```
 [  abc   def ghi   jkl    mno pqr  s ]
```

and keep the multiple (back to back) whitespaces intact.

```
 [  abc   defghi   jkl    mnopqr  s]
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19788171/regex-remove-single-whitespace

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Regex - Remove single whitespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19788171/regex-remove-single-whitespace)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**"how one should approach this problem without the use of regex?"**

You would use a state machine (much like regexes do). Algorithmically, you could track transitions and count spaces.

```
Start with SPACE = 0

while there is input
    read a character
    if (is space) {
        switch (SPACE) {
            case 0:
                SPACE++
                break
            case 1:
                Output space
                SPACE++
            case 2:
                Output space
        }
    } else
        SPACE=0
        Output char
    }
}
at the end, if SPACE=1 the string ends with space; 
decide what you want to do, whether to ignore it or output it.
```

When you encounter the first space, nothing is output but the space counter is set to 1. If, at that point, you encounter a nonspace (e.g. "HELLO WORLD"), the counter is reset and the character output, giving you HELLOWORLD. If you encounter a second space, with space counter now 1, two spaces are output and the counter is set to 2. From then on, spaces will be output normally.

With a regex, you would replace a single space between two nonspaces with the two nonspaces concatenated: '/(\S)\s(\S)/' becomes '\1\2'. This also has the problem of how to deal with beginning and ending spaces.

Comment: Wow so fast. And thank you for explaining!

Answer (score 0):

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char str[] = "  abc   def ghi   jkl    mno pqr  s ";
    int strLen;
    char result[255];
    int i, j;
    
    // get length of str
    strLen  = strlen(str);
    
    // set first char
    result[0] = str[0];
    for (i = 1, j = 1; i < strLen - 1; i++) {
        if (str[i - 1] != ' ' && str[i] == ' ' && str[i + 1] != ' '){
            continue;
        }
        result[j] = str[i];
        j++;
    }
    // set last char
    result[j] = str[strLen - 1];
    
    // add NULL at the end of the string
    result[j + 1] = 0;
    
    puts(str);
    puts(result);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
  abc   def ghi   jkl    mno pqr  s                                                                                                                                                
  abc   defghi   jkl    mnopqr  s
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void remove_spaces(std::string & spaces_string) {
  // Scan the string for spaces ignoring the start and end characters.
  size_t str_length = spaces_string.length();
  for (size_t i = 1; i < str_length - 1; i++) {
    // Check if the current character is a space AND if there is no spacing to the left or right of the character.
    if (spaces_string[i] == ' ' && (spaces_string[i - 1] != ' ' && spaces_string[i + 1] != ' ')) {
      spaces_string.erase(i, 1);
      i--;
    }
  }
  // Check the start.
  if (spaces_string[0] == ' ' && str_length > 2 && spaces_string[1] != ' ') {
    spaces_string.erase(0, 1);
  }
  // Check the end.
  if (spaces_string[str_length - 1] == ' ' && spaces_string.length() > 2 && spaces_string[str_length - 2] != ' ') {
    spaces_string.erase(0, 1);
  }

  std::cout << spaces_string << std::endl;
}

int main() {
  std::string example1 = "  Double space start  Middle double space";
  remove_spaces(example1);
  std::string example2 = "Good normal until the end   see  ";
  remove_spaces(example2);
  std::string example3 = "  ";
  remove_spaces(example3);
  std::string example4 = " ";
  remove_spaces(example4);
}
```

Output

```
  Doublespacestart  Middledoublespace
Goodnormaluntiltheend   see
```

You can use this function if you do not want to use regex.